# How to access a csv generated by a /reportstats query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, csv

Anyone have any input on how to access the format='csv' option that seems available with asynchronous reports generated via the /reportstats query?

The documentation for the reportstats query provides a format option to specify when creating an asynchronous query: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats/#columns

I am using the /reportstats query to create/schedule an async report, and I specify format=csv. The only question I have is... well. How do I access the csv report that's been supposedly scheduled?! When I try to access the report /reportstats?report_run_id=XXX query, I was hoping it would provide a url with the path to the csv, but there is no such luck.

It makes sense that the Graph only returns JSON encoded data, but I'd like to use a csv as the input for an ETL pipeline.  The reportstats query seems to support this, but so far no luck.  Anyone takers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `format=csv` parameter to the second call you make that contains the job ID.

e.g. `FB.api('/YOUR_AD_ACCT_ID/reportstats?report_run_id=123&format=csv')`.

But if you are looking to just schedule reports, you should be using the `adreportschedules` API call anyway.